Having trouble with status bar updates
The goal of this status bar is to constantly update depending on what the "admin" user has clicked (approve, deny, review, make payment). Currently, I am doing this on local storage, and I'm sure it will be a different beast when I implement a backend, but I'd rather figure out the process before I get into that. Right now, when the admin clicks "Review", I want the status bar on the status page of the user to be updated to the point of "In Review". I can't seem to diagnose the issue, as I am a web design rookie. If anyone could be of any help, that would be much appreciated.
    function getReservationRequests() {
        return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservationRequests')) || [];
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        renderMenu();
        const requestsTableBody = document.querySelector('#requestsTable tbody');
        const requests = getReservationRequests();

        requests.forEach(request => {
            const row = document.createElement('tr');
            row.innerHTML = `
                <td>${request.user}</td>
                <td>${request.status}</td>
                <td>
                    <button onclick="approveRequest('${request.user}', this)">Approve</button>
                    <button onclick="denyRequest('${request.user}', this)">Deny</button>
                    <button onclick="reviewRequest('${request.user}', this)">Review</button>
                    <button onclick="allowPayment('${request.user}', this)">Allow Payment</button>
                </td>
            `;
            requestsTableBody.appendChild(row);
        });
    });

    function approveRequest(user, button) {
        updateRequestStatus(user, 'Request approved', button);
        alert(`Request for ${user} approved.`);
    }

    function denyRequest(user, button) {
        removeRequest(user);
        const row = button.closest('tr');
        row.parentNode.removeChild(row);
        alert(`Request for ${user} denied.`);
    }

    function reviewRequest(user, button) {
        updateRequestStatus(user, 'Request in review', button);
        alert(`Request for ${user} in review.`);
    }

    function allowPayment(user, button) {
        updateRequestStatus(user, 'Payment allowed', button);
        alert(`Payment allowed for ${user}.`);
    }

    function updateRequestStatus(user, status, button) {
        const reservationRequests = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservationRequests')) || [];
        const requestIndex = reservationRequests.findIndex(request => request.user === user);

        if (requestIndex !== -1) {
            reservationRequests[requestIndex].status = status;
            localStorage.setItem('reservationRequests', JSON.stringify(reservationRequests));
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }

    function removeRequest(user) {
        let reservationRequests = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservationRequests')) || [];
        reservationRequests = reservationRequests.filter(request => request.user !== user);
        localStorage.setItem('reservationRequests', JSON.stringify(reservationRequests));
    }

<section class="status">
        <div class="status-container">
            <h2>Your Reservation Status</h2>
            <ul class="step-wizard-list">
                <li class="step-wizard-item" id="step1">
                    <span class="progress-count">1</span>
                    <span class="progress-label">Request Submitted</span>
                </li>
                <li class="step-wizard-item" id="step2">
                    <span class="progress-count">2</span>
                    <span class="progress-label">In Review</span>
                </li>
                <li class="step-wizard-item" id="step3">
                    <span class="progress-count">3</span>
                    <span class="progress-label">Request Approved/Denied</span>
                </li>
                <li class="step-wizard-item" id="step4">
                    <span class="progress-count">4</span>
                    <span class="progress-label">Payment</span>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <button id="payNowButton" style="display:none;" onclick="window.location.href='payment.html'">Pay Now</button>
        </div>
    </section>

    function getReservationStatus() {
        const userEmail = localStorage.getItem('userEmail');
        const reservationRequests = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservationRequests')) || [];
        const userRequest = reservationRequests.find(request => request.user === userEmail);

        return userRequest ? userRequest.status : 'Request not submitted';
    }

    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
        renderMenu();
        const status = getReservationStatus();
        updateStatusBar(status);

        const acceptApprovalButton = document.getElementById('acceptApprovalButton');
        if (acceptApprovalButton) {
            acceptApprovalButton.addEventListener('click', function() {
                alert('Waiting payment approval');
                updateRequestStatusForUser('Payment allowed');
                updateStatusBar('Payment allowed')
            });
        }
    });

    function updateStatusBar(status) {
        const step1 = document.getElementById('step1');
        const step2 = document.getElementById('step2');
        const step3 = document.getElementById('step3');
        const step4 = document.getElementById('step4');
        const payNowButton = document.getElementById('payNowButton');
        const acceptApprovalButton = document.createElement('button');
        }

        // Remove 'current-item' class from all steps initially
        [step1, step2, step3, step4].forEach(step => step.classList.remove('current-item'));

        switch(status) {
            case 'Request Submitted':
                step1.classList.add('current-item');
                break;
            case 'Request in review':
                step1.classList.add('current-item');
                step2.classList.add('current-item');
                break;
            case 'Request approved':
                step1.classList.add('current-item');
                step2.classList.add('current-item');
                step3.classList.add('current-item');
                document.querySelector('.status-container').appendChild(acceptApprovalButton);
                break;
            case 'Request denied':
                step1.classList.add('current-item');
                step2.classList.add('current-item');
                step3.classList.add('current-item');
                step3.querySelector('.progress-label').textContent = 'Request Denied';
                break;
            case 'Payment allowed':
                step1.classList.add('current-item');
                step2.classList.add('current-item');
                step3.classList.add('current-item');
                step4.classList.add('current-item');
                payNowButton.style.display = 'block';
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

    function updateRequestStatusForUser(status) {
        const userEmail = localStorage.getItem('userEmail');
        const reservationRequests = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('reservationRequests')) || [];
        const requestIndex = reservationRequests.findIndex(request => request.user === userEmail);

        if (requestIndex !== -1) {
            reservationRequests[requestIndex].status = status;
            localStorage.setItem('reservationRequests', JSON.stringify(reservationRequests));
            window.location.reload();
        }
    }


Have you tried error handling to diagnose the issue?

Why does your post have two separate pieces of Javascript, and why does each one have a different DOMContentLoaded event listener?

@BrettDonald two different html files that are interacting with each other

@QianZhang did some console log updates, currently trying to pinpoint the issue
